# populate form with spreadsheet data

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I would like to set up a google form to record users' bids, and show the current highest bid from previous form responses. I saw the question [Is it possible to populate a google form from a google spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394049/is-it-possible-to-populate-a-google-form-from-a-google-spreadsheet) and seems like this is still not an available feature?

Comment: Did you look at the top-rated answer to that question, posted in 2013?  It is possible, at least theoretically.  I've done this onece or twice, a couple of year ago.  If you can't get it to work, let me know and I'l hunt for the code.

Comment: @Beartums do you mean this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108511/is-it-possible-to-prefill-a-google-form-using-data-from-a-google-spreadsheet 
I don't get where I am supposed to put the code from buildUrls etc and how to link it in form.

Comment: No.  I was actually talking about [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app).  In google drive you create a new apps script, use the FormApp service to open your form and associate a spreadsheet.  look through the spreadsheet using the spreadsheetApp service, get the value you want, and plug it into the form.  The FormApp service has only been available in Google Apps since 2013, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my above comments: the link you provide gives you the detail.  THe google documentation I link to will fill in all the options.

The steps, as I remember them are:

1. Create your form, get the unique form id
2. Create a script in Google drive.  In the script:
3. Open the form using the form id
4. Find the appropriate value in the last response
5. create a response.
6. Add your default value
7. get the prefilled url (`.toPrefilledUrl()`)
8. direct the user to the prefilled url (email, web page, etc.)

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. I know what you mean here, but since the prefilled url contains the actual values of the cells, in my bidding app doesn't that mean every time when someone fills out the form I need to send out a new link to the form with the latest bid embedded in the url?